# How to check the number of keys being pressed in a keydown event

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to implement keyboard shortcuts on the browser. When the event listener is fired, I want to make sure that only a certain key combination is being pressed and nothing else.
For example, if I want to register the key "A" as a shortcut, the code might look like the following.

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
    if (event.key.toLowerCase() === "a" && numberOfKeysCurrentlyBeingPressed === 1) {
        // Do something
    }
});
```

This would be triggered for `A` and not for something like `Ctrl` + `A` or `A` + `B`.

I thought about counting and keeping track of the number of keys being pressed with keydown and keyup event listeners, but some keys on some systems will trigger only one event listener(keydown or keyup) and not the other. Also, there are some inconsistencies with this approach, not making it a viable solution.

I'm looking for a way to know exactly how many keys are being pressed when keydown event listener is fired so that I can compare the number with the number of keys involved in a keyboard shortcut combination.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `keyup` event and `keydown` you could keep track of how many keys are pressed like so:

```
var keyPresses = 0;

window.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  keyPresses--
})

window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  if (!e.repeat) {
    keyPresses++
  }
  if (e.key.toLowerCase() === 'a' && keyPresses === 1) {
    //do something
  }
})
```

Comment: I think you're right, that keydowns and keyups will have to be counted, although I would keep just one variable ... number of keys _currently_ pressed, e.g. `numKeysCurrentlyPressed`, or just `pressedCount`, which you'd increment and decrement. The tricky part is that a key being _held down_ keeps emitting keyDown events, which you have to discard and not count, but you can tell which those are because the event will come with `repeat: true` set. So, `on keyDown if ! repeat pressedCount++`

Comment: Yeah this is a better solution, I have written the code using this method instead